# How to share files between Win XP (guest) and Win 10 (host) on vmware?

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

How can I share guest OS files / folders and access them on Host machine? Host = Windows 10 Enterprise Guest = Windows XP. I tried numerous guides online but nothing worked. Both machines can ping each other. Can any one point me to any article or tool to achieve this task?

Comment: what vmware product are you using on your host? Vmware workstation?

Comment: yes workstation

Comment: I have this configuration here except my host is Windows 11.  Networking does not work in any secure way. I transfer files on USB Key. Issue is SMBv1 only for XP.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use vmware shared folders
2. you can use standard windows file sharing (like \host\share or \vm\share)

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/virtualization-coach/how-do-i-work-with-shared-folders-in-vmware-workstation/

Comment: 1. Doesn't shared folder mount a folder from host in guest machine and not vice versa. I am looking to mount the guest folder in host.
2. Tried but win 10 doesn't notice any shares from Xp

Comment: @AhmedRana for 1 it only shares host folders to the vm(s), but you can add files to it from the VM(s).

Comment: Thanks. I know about that. There are certain environment on guest which I will set Eclipse as output folders etc. which I not possible via sharing host drive.